# How do I add values of two dataframes which has some values of one column in common

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have two dataframes df1 and df2

The common column is CustomerId and the other column is the amount spent. The data is for different months and I need to find the total amount spent by a person in these 2 dataframes combined.
The catch in this problem is not all CustomerId are the same in both dataframes. Some are different/new as well

How do I ensure that revenue values get added for the respective CustomerID?

```
column_values = ['Revenue']

df_out = df1[column_values] + df2[column_values]
          
df_out['CustomerID'] = df1['CustomerID']
```

I tried this but realised that the CustomerID column would be carried forward and would not take into account the different/new values in `df2['CustomerID']`

Thank you!

Comment: This would be clearer if you provided sample data, but it sounds like you should join/merge on `CustomerID`.

Comment: Can you please provide your dataframes?

Comment: try `df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).groupby('CustomerID', as_index=False).sum()`

Comment: thank you @jezrael I came up with this very solution later on. It works